# how can I customize the output of validation errors in a mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I get this syntax from errors when I do an insert like this:

[image]

I get this error syntax in the `err` property. In this case the `documento` attribute and the`correo` attribute are not unique.
in the same `err.message` a text string is built where it includes the fields and the errors for which in this case the registry insertion could not be done. How can I do something like this, with the previous example so that the output is like this:

{ 
            err: {
                 .
                 .
                 .
            "message": "documento debe ser unico\n correo debe ser unico\n"
            }
         }

this is my full code:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

    let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    let usuarioSchema = new Schema({
        nombres: {
            type: String,
        },
        documento: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: [true, 'documento debe ser único']
        },
        correo: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: [true, 'Correo  debe ser único']
        },
        ultimo_inicio_sesion: {
            type: Date,
            default: null
        },
        contrasena: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Contraseña es necesario']
        },
        rol:
        {
            type: String
        }

    })


    usuarioSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {

        let user = this;
        let userObject = user.toObject();

        return userObject;
    }


    usuarioSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: '{PATH} debe de ser único' });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('usuarios_', usuarioSchema);
```

How can do it?

I need the output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your error you can place a check on the basis of error code returned from the mongodb for unique value (code 11000).

```
if(code === 11000) {
  return "Value already exists"
}
```

for further reference do read the documentation for [error for unique value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html#unique-index-and-missing-field).

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem. there are cases where there can be many errors at the same time, for example there can be more than one field that must be unique and they are not, I am trying to get the errors of my model when inserting, in a single line. look at the `message` attribute that is the summary of my errors, and what I want to customize to the structure I put. https://i.imgur.com/3N6Igl1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What about [custom validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators)?

Code example:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  phone: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        return /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(v);
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is not a valid phone number!`
    },
    required: [true, 'User phone number required']
  }
});
```

Where `message` property returns custom message.

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem. there are cases where there can be many errors at the same time, for example there can be more than one field that must be unique and they are not, I am trying to get the errors of my model when inserting, in a single line. look at the `message` attribute that is the summary of my errors, and what I want to customize to the structure I put. https://i.imgur.com/3N6Igl1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Afaik I know this is not possible, but as a simple workaround you could just iterate over the `errors` and build up your the error-message yourself. Something like:

```js
const validationResult = {
  message: 'Usuario validation failed: documento: documento debe de ser unico, correo: correo debe de ser unico',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: {
    documento: {
      message: 'documento debe de ser unico',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
    },
    correo: {
      message: 'correo debe de ser unico',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
    },
  },
};


function buildErrorMessage(validationResult) {
  const errorMessages = [];
  for (const error in validationResult.errors) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(validationResult.errors, error)) {
        errorMessages.push(validationResult.errors[error].message);
    }
  }
  return errorMessages.join('\n');
}


console.log(buildErrorMessage(validationResult))
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it does not fit what I need.